# Rails 3.2: jquery file upload not refreshing page after file upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

So I have an application where I'm using jquery file upload with paperclip to dynamically add files to my database.  Everything is working except that when I add a new file (after clicking the 'Start upload' button), the page is not refreshed (but the file is properly inserted into the database and sent to amazon s3).

I checked out the console and noticed that when I upload the file there is only a PUT request and no GET request like there should be.

By the way, I also have a demo app that has the same code as my real app, which is working. And I noticed in the demo app when you upload a file there is a PUT request that is immediately followed by a GET request.

So I put in alerts in different callbacks, and found out that there is an issue with the 'done' function. Here is the relevant code from 'done':

```
// Callback for successful uploads:
            done: function (e, data) { alert('done');
                var that = $(this).data('fileupload'),
                    template;
                if (data.context) { alert('done: if');
                    data.context.each(function (index) {
                        var file = ($.isArray(data.result) &&
                                data.result[index]) || {error: 'emptyResult'};
                        if (file.error) { alert('done: file.error');
                            that._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(1);
                        }
                        that._transition($(this)).done(
                            function () { alert('done: function');
                                var node = $(this);
                                template = that._renderDownload([file])
                                    .css('height', node.height())
                                    .replaceAll(node);
                                that._forceReflow(template);
                                that._transition(template).done(
                                    function () { alert('done: function2');
                                        data.context = $(this);
                                        that._trigger('completed', e, data);
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );
                    });
```

In the demo app, all of the alert messages in the above code are hit. However, in my real app only up to alert('done: if') is hit.  Which means that _renderDownload and _forceReflow are not called, which is causing the list of files not to be refreshed until I reload the page.

Also in case this helps, I added alerts to all relevant callbacks in both the demo app and real app to figure out if something wasn't being called, I'll list out the alerts that were called in order for each (note: these alerts are called after I hit the 'Start upload' button):

**Demo app:**

```
_startHandler
start
send
done
done: if statement
done: function 
_renderDownload
_forceReflow
done: function2
stop
stop2
```

**Real app:**

```
_startHandler
start
send
done
done: if
stop
stop2
```